# [[ strings ]] with nested [[ strings ]] in lua?

Tags: lua

The example in https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html
shows:

```
page = [[
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>An HTML Page</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
     <A HREF="http://www.lua.org">Lua</A>
     [[a text between double brackets]]
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
    ]]
```

however this gives me an error on the `/` in `</BODY>`.

```
lua54: html.lua:9: unexpected symbol near '/'
```

has something changed since the book was published?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use another level of long bracket:

```
page = [=[
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>An HTML Page</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
     <A HREF="http://www.lua.org">Lua</A>
     [[a text between double brackets]]
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
    ]=]
```

The header says "This first edition was written for Lua 5.0", this was changed in [Lua 5.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.1):

> The long string/long comment syntax ([[string]]) does not allow nesting. You can use the new syntax ([=[string]=]) in these cases. (See compile-time option LUA_COMPAT_LSTR in luaconf.h.)

Comment: Just bought the 4th edition ;-)